# How to add mark on seekbar on specfic position(on run time).?

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar

[image]

I need to add multiple  mark on seekbar like above image (But on run time).

e.g

May be i need to add two marks one on 10sec and other on 44sec.

So how can i add mark on specific position using time??

Comment: Did you got the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use this Class:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ViewConfiguration;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.hkhaksar.shikat.R;

/**
 * Widget that lets users select a minimum and maximum value on a given
 * numerical range. The range value types can be one of Long, Double, Integer,
 * Float, Short, Byte or BigDecimal.<br />
 * <br />
 * Improved {@link MotionEvent} handling for smoother use, anti-aliased painting
 * for improved aesthetics.
 * 
 * @author Stephan Tittel (stephan.tittel@kom.tu-darmstadt.de)
 * @author Peter Sinnott (psinnott@gmail.com)
 * @author Thomas Barrasso (tbarrasso@sevenplusandroid.org)
 * 
 * @param <T>
 *            The Number type of the range values. One of Long, Double, Integer,
 *            Float, Short, Byte or BigDecimal.
 */
public class RangeSeekBar<T extends Number> extends ImageView {
    private final Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    private final Bitmap thumbImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            getResources(), R.drawable.leftithumb);
    private final Bitmap thumbPressedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            getResources(), R.drawable.leftithumb);
    private final float thumbWidth = thumbImage.getWidth();
    private final float thumbHalfWidth = 0.5f * thumbWidth;
    private final float thumbHalfHeight = 0.5f * thumbImage.getHeight();
    private final float lineHeight = 0.3f * thumbHalfHeight;
    private final float padding = thumbHalfWidth;
    private final T absoluteMinValue, absoluteMaxValue;
    private final NumberType numberType;
    private final double absoluteMinValuePrim, absoluteMaxValuePrim;
    private double normalizedMinValue = 0d;
    private double normalizedMaxValue = 1d;
    private Thumb pressedThumb = null;
    private boolean notifyWhileDragging = false;
    private OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener<T> listener;

    /**
     * Default color of a {@link RangeSeekBar}, #FF33B5E5. This is also known as
     * "Ice Cream Sandwich" blue.
     */
    public static final int DEFAULT_COLOR = Color.argb(0xFF, 0x2F, 0xB5, 0x9B);

    /**
     * An invalid pointer id.
     */
    public static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = 255;

    // Localized constants from MotionEvent for compatibility
    // with API < 8 "Froyo".
    public static final int ACTION_POINTER_UP = 0x6,
            ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK = 0x0000ff00,
            ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT = 8;

    private float mDownMotionX;
    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

    /**
     * On touch, this offset plus the scaled value from the position of the
     * touch will form the progress value. Usually 0.
     */
    float mTouchProgressOffset;

    private int mScaledTouchSlop;
    private boolean mIsDragging;

    /**
     * Creates a new RangeSeekBar.
     * 
     * @param absoluteMinValue
     *            The minimum value of the selectable range.
     * @param absoluteMaxValue
     *            The maximum value of the selectable range.
     * @param context
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             Will be thrown if min/max value type is not one of Long,
     *             Double, Integer, Float, Short, Byte or BigDecimal.
     */
    public RangeSeekBar(T absoluteMinValue, T absoluteMaxValue, Context context)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {
        super(context);
        this.absoluteMinValue = absoluteMinValue;
        this.absoluteMaxValue = absoluteMaxValue;
        absoluteMinValuePrim = absoluteMinValue.doubleValue();
        absoluteMaxValuePrim = absoluteMaxValue.doubleValue();
        numberType = NumberType.fromNumber(absoluteMinValue);

        // make RangeSeekBar focusable. This solves focus handling issues in
        // case EditText widgets are being used along with the RangeSeekBar
        // within ScollViews.
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        init();
    }

    private final void init() {
        mScaledTouchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(getContext())
                .getScaledTouchSlop();
    }

    public boolean isNotifyWhileDragging() {
        return notifyWhileDragging;
    }

    /**
     * Should the widget notify the listener callback while the user is still
     * dragging a thumb? Default is false.
     * 
     * @param flag
     */
    public void setNotifyWhileDragging(boolean flag) {
        this.notifyWhileDragging = flag;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the absolute minimum value of the range that has been set at
     * construction time.
     * 
     * @return The absolute minimum value of the range.
     */
    public T getAbsoluteMinValue() {
        return absoluteMinValue;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the absolute maximum value of the range that has been set at
     * construction time.
     * 
     * @return The absolute maximum value of the range.
     */
    public T getAbsoluteMaxValue() {
        return absoluteMaxValue;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the currently selected min value.
     * 
     * @return The currently selected min value.
     */
    public T getSelectedMinValue() {
        return normalizedToValue(normalizedMinValue);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the currently selected minimum value. The widget will be invalidated
     * and redrawn.
     * 
     * @param value
     *            The Number value to set the minimum value to. Will be clamped
     *            to given absolute minimum/maximum range.
     */
    public void setSelectedMinValue(T value) {
        // in case absoluteMinValue == absoluteMaxValue, avoid division by zero
        // when normalizing.
        if (0 == (absoluteMaxValuePrim - absoluteMinValuePrim)) {
            setNormalizedMinValue(0d);
        } else {
            setNormalizedMinValue(valueToNormalized(value));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the currently selected max value.
     * 
     * @return The currently selected max value.
     */
    public T getSelectedMaxValue() {
        return normalizedToValue(normalizedMaxValue);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the currently selected maximum value. The widget will be invalidated
     * and redrawn.
     * 
     * @param value
     *            The Number value to set the maximum value to. Will be clamped
     *            to given absolute minimum/maximum range.
     */
    public void setSelectedMaxValue(T value) {
        // in case absoluteMinValue == absoluteMaxValue, avoid division by zero
        // when normalizing.
        if (0 == (absoluteMaxValuePrim - absoluteMinValuePrim)) {
            setNormalizedMaxValue(1d);
        } else {
            setNormalizedMaxValue(valueToNormalized(value));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Registers given listener callback to notify about changed selected
     * values.
     * 
     * @param listener
     *            The listener to notify about changed selected values.
     */
    public void setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(
            OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener<T> listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Handles thumb selection and movement. Notifies listener callback on
     * certain events.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if (!isEnabled())
            return false;

        int pointerIndex;

        final int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // Remember where the motion event started
            mActivePointerId = event.getPointerId(event.getPointerCount() - 1);
            pointerIndex = event.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
            mDownMotionX = event.getX(pointerIndex);

            pressedThumb = evalPressedThumb(mDownMotionX);

            // Only handle thumb presses.
            if (pressedThumb == null)
                return super.onTouchEvent(event);

            setPressed(true);
            invalidate();
            onStartTrackingTouch();
            trackTouchEvent(event);
            attemptClaimDrag();

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (pressedThumb != null) {

                if (mIsDragging) {
                    trackTouchEvent(event);
                } else {
                    // Scroll to follow the motion event
                    pointerIndex = event.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
                    final float x = event.getX(pointerIndex);

                    if (Math.abs(x - mDownMotionX) > mScaledTouchSlop) {
                        setPressed(true);
                        invalidate();
                        onStartTrackingTouch();
                        trackTouchEvent(event);
                        attemptClaimDrag();
                    }
                }

                if (notifyWhileDragging && listener != null) {
                    listener.onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(this,
                            getSelectedMinValue(), getSelectedMaxValue());
                }
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (mIsDragging) {
                trackTouchEvent(event);
                onStopTrackingTouch();
                setPressed(false);
            } else {
                // Touch up when we never crossed the touch slop threshold
                // should be interpreted as a tap-seek to that location.
                onStartTrackingTouch();
                trackTouchEvent(event);
                onStopTrackingTouch();
            }

            pressedThumb = null;
            invalidate();
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(this,
                        getSelectedMinValue(), getSelectedMaxValue());
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: {
            final int index = event.getPointerCount() - 1;
            // final int index = ev.getActionIndex();
            mDownMotionX = event.getX(index);
            mActivePointerId = event.getPointerId(index);
            invalidate();
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            onSecondaryPointerUp(event);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            if (mIsDragging) {
                onStopTrackingTouch();
                setPressed(false);
            }
            invalidate(); // see above explanation
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private final void onSecondaryPointerUp(MotionEvent ev) {
        final int pointerIndex = (ev.getAction() & ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;

        final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
        if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
            // This was our active pointer going up. Choose
            // a new active pointer and adjust accordingly.
            // TODO: Make this decision more intelligent.
            final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
            mDownMotionX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
            mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
        }
    }

    private final void trackTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        final int pointerIndex = event.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
        final float x = event.getX(pointerIndex);

        if (Thumb.MIN.equals(pressedThumb)) {
            setNormalizedMinValue(screenToNormalized(x));
        } else if (Thumb.MAX.equals(pressedThumb)) {
            setNormalizedMaxValue(screenToNormalized(x));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Tries to claim the user's drag motion, and requests disallowing any
     * ancestors from stealing events in the drag.
     */
    private void attemptClaimDrag() {
        if (getParent() != null) {
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is called when the user has started touching this widget.
     */
    void onStartTrackingTouch() {
        mIsDragging = true;
    }

    /**
     * This is called when the user either releases his touch or the touch is
     * canceled.
     */
    void onStopTrackingTouch() {
        mIsDragging = false;
    }

    /**
     * Ensures correct size of the widget.
     */
    @Override
    protected synchronized void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec,
            int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int width = 200;
        if (MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED != MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec)) {
            width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        }
        int height = thumbImage.getHeight();
        if (MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED != MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec)) {
            height = Math.min(height, MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec));
        }
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }

    /**
     * Draws the widget on the given canvas.
     */
    @Override
    protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        // draw seek bar background line
        final RectF rect = new RectF(padding,
                0.5f * (getHeight() - lineHeight), getWidth() - padding,
                0.5f * (getHeight() + lineHeight));
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);

        // draw seek bar active range line
        rect.left = normalizedToScreen(normalizedMinValue);
        rect.right = normalizedToScreen(normalizedMaxValue);

        // orange color
        paint.setColor(DEFAULT_COLOR);
        canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);

        // draw minimum thumb
        drawThumb(normalizedToScreen(normalizedMinValue),
                Thumb.MIN.equals(pressedThumb), canvas);

        // draw maximum thumb
        drawThumb(normalizedToScreen(normalizedMaxValue),
                Thumb.MAX.equals(pressedThumb), canvas);
    }

    /**
     * Overridden to save instance state when device orientation changes. This
     * method is called automatically if you assign an id to the RangeSeekBar
     * widget using the {@link #setId(int)} method. Other members of this class
     * than the normalized min and max values don't need to be saved.
     */
    @Override
    protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable("SUPER", super.onSaveInstanceState());
        bundle.putDouble("MIN", normalizedMinValue);
        bundle.putDouble("MAX", normalizedMaxValue);
        return bundle;
    }

    /**
     * Overridden to restore instance state when device orientation changes.
     * This method is called automatically if you assign an id to the
     * RangeSeekBar widget using the {@link #setId(int)} method.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable parcel) {
        final Bundle bundle = (Bundle) parcel;
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(bundle.getParcelable("SUPER"));
        normalizedMinValue = bundle.getDouble("MIN");
        normalizedMaxValue = bundle.getDouble("MAX");
    }

    /**
     * Draws the "normal" resp. "pressed" thumb image on specified x-coordinate.
     * 
     * @param screenCoord
     *            The x-coordinate in screen space where to draw the image.
     * @param pressed
     *            Is the thumb currently in "pressed" state?
     * @param canvas
     *            The canvas to draw upon.
     */
    private void drawThumb(float screenCoord, boolean pressed, Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(pressed ? thumbPressedImage : thumbImage, screenCoord
                - thumbHalfWidth,
                (float) ((0.5f * getHeight()) - thumbHalfHeight), paint);
    }

    /**
     * Decides which (if any) thumb is touched by the given x-coordinate.
     * 
     * @param touchX
     *            The x-coordinate of a touch event in screen space.
     * @return The pressed thumb or null if none has been touched.
     */
    private Thumb evalPressedThumb(float touchX) {
        Thumb result = null;
        boolean minThumbPressed = isInThumbRange(touchX, normalizedMinValue);
        boolean maxThumbPressed = isInThumbRange(touchX, normalizedMaxValue);
        if (minThumbPressed && maxThumbPressed) {
            // if both thumbs are pressed (they lie on top of each other),
            // choose the one with more room to drag. this avoids "stalling" the
            // thumbs in a corner, not being able to drag them apart anymore.
            result = (touchX / getWidth() > 0.5f) ? Thumb.MIN : Thumb.MAX;
        } else if (minThumbPressed) {
            result = Thumb.MIN;
        } else if (maxThumbPressed) {
            result = Thumb.MAX;
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Decides if given x-coordinate in screen space needs to be interpreted as
     * "within" the normalized thumb x-coordinate.
     * 
     * @param touchX
     *            The x-coordinate in screen space to check.
     * @param normalizedThumbValue
     *            The normalized x-coordinate of the thumb to check.
     * @return true if x-coordinate is in thumb range, false otherwise.
     */
    private boolean isInThumbRange(float touchX, double normalizedThumbValue) {
        return Math.abs(touchX - normalizedToScreen(normalizedThumbValue)) <= thumbHalfWidth;
    }

    /**
     * Sets normalized min value to value so that 0 <= value <= normalized max
     * value <= 1. The View will get invalidated when calling this method.
     * 
     * @param value
     *            The new normalized min value to set.
     */
    public void setNormalizedMinValue(double value) {
        normalizedMinValue = Math.max(0d,
                Math.min(1d, Math.min(value, normalizedMaxValue)));
        invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * Sets normalized max value to value so that 0 <= normalized min value <=
     * value <= 1. The View will get invalidated when calling this method.
     * 
     * @param value
     *            The new normalized max value to set.
     */
    public void setNormalizedMaxValue(double value) {
        normalizedMaxValue = Math.max(0d,
                Math.min(1d, Math.max(value, normalizedMinValue)));
        invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * Converts a normalized value to a Number object in the value space between
     * absolute minimum and maximum.
     * 
     * @param normalized
     * @return
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private T normalizedToValue(double normalized) {
        return (T) numberType.toNumber(absoluteMinValuePrim + normalized
                * (absoluteMaxValuePrim - absoluteMinValuePrim));
    }

    /**
     * Converts the given Number value to a normalized double.
     * 
     * @param value
     *            The Number value to normalize.
     * @return The normalized double.
     */
    private double valueToNormalized(T value) {
        if (0 == absoluteMaxValuePrim - absoluteMinValuePrim) {
            // prevent division by zero, simply return 0.
            return 0d;
        }
        return (value.doubleValue() - absoluteMinValuePrim)
                / (absoluteMaxValuePrim - absoluteMinValuePrim);
    }

    /**
     * Converts a normalized value into screen space.
     * 
     * @param normalizedCoord
     *            The normalized value to convert.
     * @return The converted value in screen space.
     */
    private float normalizedToScreen(double normalizedCoord) {
        return (float) (padding + normalizedCoord * (getWidth() - 2 * padding));
    }

    /**
     * Converts screen space x-coordinates into normalized values.
     * 
     * @param screenCoord
     *            The x-coordinate in screen space to convert.
     * @return The normalized value.
     */
    private double screenToNormalized(float screenCoord) {
        int width = getWidth();
        if (width <= 2 * padding) {
            // prevent division by zero, simply return 0.
            return 0d;
        } else {
            double result = (screenCoord - padding) / (width - 2 * padding);
            return Math.min(1d, Math.max(0d, result));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Callback listener interface to notify about changed range values.
     * 
     * @author Stephan Tittel (stephan.tittel@kom.tu-darmstadt.de)
     * 
     * @param <T>
     *            The Number type the RangeSeekBar has been declared with.
     */
    public interface OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener<T> {
        public void onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(RangeSeekBar<?> bar,
                T minValue, T maxValue);
    }

    /**
     * Thumb constants (min and max).
     */
    private static enum Thumb {
        MIN, MAX
    };

    /**
     * Utility enumaration used to convert between Numbers and doubles.
     * 
     * @author Stephan Tittel (stephan.tittel@kom.tu-darmstadt.de)
     * 
     */
    private static enum NumberType {
        LONG, DOUBLE, INTEGER, FLOAT, SHORT, BYTE, BIG_DECIMAL;

        public static <E extends Number> NumberType fromNumber(E value)
                throws IllegalArgumentException {
            if (value instanceof Long) {
                return LONG;
            }
            if (value instanceof Double) {
                return DOUBLE;
            }
            if (value instanceof Integer) {
                return INTEGER;
            }
            if (value instanceof Float) {
                return FLOAT;
            }
            if (value instanceof Short) {
                return SHORT;
            }
            if (value instanceof Byte) {
                return BYTE;
            }
            if (value instanceof BigDecimal) {
                return BIG_DECIMAL;
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number class '"
                    + value.getClass().getName() + "' is not supported");
        }

        public Number toNumber(double value) {
            switch (this) {
            case LONG:
                return new Long((long) value);
            case DOUBLE:
                return value;
            case INTEGER:
                return new Integer((int) value);
            case FLOAT:
                return new Float(value);
            case SHORT:
                return new Short((short) value);
            case BYTE:
                return new Byte((byte) value);
            case BIG_DECIMAL:
                return new BigDecimal(value);
            }
            throw new InstantiationError("can't convert " + this
                    + " to a Number object");
        }
    }
}
```

replace LinearLayout to xml file instead of your seekbar. Like this:

Add these codes for define and add custom seekbar view in your java code class:

```
RangeSeekBar<Integer> sbPrice;
llPrice = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.llPrice);
sbPrice = new RangeSeekBar<Integer>(0, 5000, ctx);
llPrice.addView(sbPrice);
```

Now you must implement OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener in your java class.(like activity, fragment, etc)

```
sbPrice.setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(this);
```

use this method to change seeker method:

```
@Override
public void onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(RangeSeekBar<?> bar,
        Integer minValue, Integer maxValue) {
    tvValMin.setText(String.valueOf(minValue));
    tvValMax.setText(String.valueOf(maxValue));

}
```

you can get min and max values by these codes:

```
sbPrice.getSelectedMinValue();
sbPrice.getSelectedMaxValue();
```

Comment: By mistake your answer is accepted from my account. I don't know its working or not :)
BTW how can i use this class @H.Khaksar

Comment: @NisarAhmad I complete it. you can see how to use it. Good Luck